# How can I bind Autocomplete to a dialog within Serene Template

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-autocomplete

If you go to this online sample template and see what I am talking about:
[Serene Template Samples](http://serenity.is/demo/Northwind/Customer)

When you clicked on "New Customer", the jquery modal dialog gets created via typescript.  This dialog div and form doesn't get created within the parent page until you click the button.

I need a way to bind the autocomplete within the jquery dialog onto one of the fields, but I can't get it to work.  I can bind it onto the main page but since the dialog doesn't get created until later, how can you bind it when this dialog gets created?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to muddle my way through and not having familiarity with typescript and serene template.  I added the entire autocomplete call in the constructor of xxxxxDialog.ts file and it seems to work well.

```
    constructor() {
        super();
        $('[name=EmpNum]').autocomplete({
            minLength: 6,
            autoFocus: true,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/services/adlookup/autocompleteuserlookup",  

                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {//data needs to be array of objects
                            return { label: item.LastName + ", " + item.FirstName + " (" + item.Descriptions + ")", value: item.EmpNum + "|" + item.UserName + "|" + item.LastName + "|" + item.FirstName + "|" + item.EmailAddress + "|" + item.WorkPhone };//item is each item in array item.LastName
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            focus: function () {
                $(".ui-helper-hidden-accessible").hide();  
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        })
        .on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) { //fill in data after it had been selected
                var t = $(this),      
                label = (e.type == 'autocompleteresponse' ? ui.content[0].label : ui.item.label),
                value = (e.type == 'autocompleteresponse' ? ui.content[0].value : ui.item.value);
                var adprop = value.split("|");
                return false;
            });
    }//end constructor
```

Comment: Nice one, i'd prefer to wrap it into a simple widget though. There is a sample in guide.